# How do I add a src=URL before the body element in a React component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am attempting to add a 'LikeThis' source URL so that I can render social sharing buttons on my page. Because React does not use a normal HTML setup, I'm not sure how to insert this src before the body:

```
<!-- Go to www.addthis.com/dashboard to customize your tools -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-56156bb12bbbe571" async="async"></script>
```

Comment: You could put it in the `<head>` so that you are promised to have it before the body loads.

Comment: Is it possible to access <head> within a react component?

Comment: No - what exactly are you trying to do? If you put a script into your body/head, the contents of the script (lets use jQuery as an example) will be available to all other scripts (that run after the initial script is loaded).

Comment: You might also find the [react-async-script](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-async-script) package useful

Comment: I am using the site 'AddThis' to manage my social sharing buttons. After loading the above src, all I need to do is add: 
<div class="addthis_sharing_toolbox"></div> to the page to render the buttons. Where can I load the script within the component?

Comment: The NFL Helmet lib might also be helpful: https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet